# How do you graph ordinal logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, regression, ordinal

I ran an ordinal logistic regression on two variables, the dependent variable having values ranging from 0-6, and the independent variable having values from 0-12. I want to graph this relationship in R, but I don't know what command to use to graph ordinal logistic regression. Is there a specific command for this? 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how ggplot2 would handle this. You should psot data. `as.numeric` will convert an ordered factor to a 1-based integer sequence. You could use `with dfrm, table(dep, indep))` and use a ggroupd `barplot` to display or you could use jittering to separate values using `plot( as.numeric(y) ~ jitter(indep), data= dfrm)`

Comment: Thanks. I converted the dependent variable into a numeric, but I realize that the fact that both my dependent and independent variables contain discrete values means that any graphs I create probably won't be that helpful. I tried using the cdplot command to make a conditional density plot to show the probability of each value of x equaling each value of y-- does this seem like a reasonable graph to use?

Comment: Plotting tabulations of discrete by discrete variables have many methods in the vcd-package. You might use `mosaic`.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that out. Thanks for your help!